# Question on $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Prove that 
$$
f \in L^\infty([0,1];\mathbb{R}) \iff f \in L^p([0,1];\mathbb{R}) \ \ \forall p \ge 1 \ \text{ and } \sup_{p\ge 1}\|f\|_p<\infty.
$$
**Remark:** I've already solve the first part, i.e. if $f \in L^\infty([0,1];\mathbb{R})$ then ...

Comment: I'm able to prove one way: "$\Rightarrow$"

Comment: Then you should have said so. And what about the other direction? Any ideas?

Comment: If you assumed that $f\notin L_\infty$, then given a positive integer $n$, there is a set $E_n$ with positive measure such that $|f(x)|\ge n$ for all $x\in E_n$. What can you say about $\Vert f\Vert_p$ for $p$ large? What can you then say, keeping in mind that $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer?

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks! Is there a more direct approach?

Comment: I'd say that is *quite* direct! It is straight from the definition of $L^\infty$ after all.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It is far from direct, in fact it is indirect, to be more precise it is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @albmiz-mth I meant it to be a proof by contraposition.

Comment: @DavidMitra I know, my previous comment wasn't meant for you.

Comment: The word “direct” has two meanings. I meant the opposite of using long, tortuous arguments that involve a whole pile of seemingly unrelated tools. Some proofs in mathematics are like that, sometimes even by necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define for $n$ integer $E_n:=\{x\in [0,1],g(x)\geqslant n\}$, where $g$ is a measurable function in the class of $f$ for equality almost everywhere.

Then $|g(x)|^p\chi_{E_n}(x)\geqslant n^p\mu(E_n)$, which gives, integrating that 
$$n\mu(E_n)^{1/p}\leqslant \sup_{p\geqslant 1}\lVert g\rVert_p=:M<\infty.$$
So $\mu(E_n)\leqslant \left(\frac Mn\right)^p$. For $n\geqslant M+1$, this gives that for any $p>1$,
$$\mu(E_n)\leqslant \left(\frac M{M+1}\right)^p,$$
and taking the limit $\lim_{p\to +\infty}$, we get that $\mu(E_{M+1})=0$, hence $f\in L^\infty$.